# Find eigenvalues given A and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following problem:[image]

I know how to compute the eigenvectors given the matrix and then finding eigenvalues. I could turn A into a triangular matrix and then compute for lambdas, but I wanted to know if there was another procedure by using the eigenvectors and A to find the eigenvalues.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Refer back to the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors: $M$ a matrix;  we say $v$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $\mu$ if $Mv=\mu v$.

Comment: and you need just to multiply the first line of **$A$** by $v$ and compare with first component of $v$

Comment: first line as in column or row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
13 & 2 & -18\\
14 & 1 & -18\\
10 & 2 & -15
\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
-1\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
3\\
3
\end{bmatrix}=-3\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
-1\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Thus, $-3$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Try the same strategy for the other two eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply the matrix and the eigenvector $(A*v)$, you obtain $\lambda*v$, so from that you will see what is the actual lambda. Just a consequence of the definition.

Comment: Do I do this by columns? say v1 (eigenvector) times a (1st column of A)

Comment: yes, just a standard operation :)